# Ошибка подключения: 26 к MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

Добрый день, при попытки подключения проекта к уже имеющейся базе данных выдается ошибка:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Строка подключения:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=***.***.***.**\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=NameBase;User ID=Administrator;Password=********" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

При этом SQL Server Object Explorer VS - подключен к этому удаленному серверу и видит базу.

sqlbrowser.exe и UDP порт 1434 добавлены в исключения, так же добавлен в исключение порт 1433 (где то у Microsofta он упоминался). Пробовал \ и "\\" в строке соединения.

Что еще может быть?

Answer (score 1):

Помогло, обновление до последней версии [Windows PowerShell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395)
И строка подключения:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=***.***.***.**\SQLEXPRESS;Database=NameBase;User ID=Administrator;Password=********" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Comment: Вот автор вопроса молодец! разобрался, но сам написал ответ - теперь на одни грабельки в огромной заваленной гроблями пустыне стало меньше